# Remove UIElement from the tree UI Doesn't Delete it definitely

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Custom control that allow me to add/remove some UIElements (Path Objects)

When Add Each element I asigne it one name something like _28_29_1, _28_29_2 ... _28_29_3 using this code

```
ContadorSimbolos += 1;
string Nombre = string.Format("_{0}_{1}_{2}", this.Name, simbolo.Id, ContadorSimbolos.ToString().Trim());
Path MyPath = SimbolTools.TextToPath(simbolo.Path, Nombre);
PanelInferior1Contenedor.Children.Add(MyPath);
this.RegisterName(Nombre, MyPath);
```

Until here everything Works fine, But now if I remove one of those objects created in the prior stage it perform the visual deletion

```
PanelInferior2Contenedor.Children.Remove(MyPath);
```

But If I use

```
nombre = string.Format("_{0}_{1}_{2}", this.Name, IdSimbolo, i);
PathEncontrado = this.FindName(nombre) as Path;
```

To find that element by name, it still found it.

How can I do to remove it definitely?

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you use an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) and proper [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) as opposed to creating and manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF. Your current approach has a number of drawbacks: It is too cumbersome, it requires too much code to do less. It is prone to all sorts of subtle issues due to the complexity of the Visual Tree, and it is not workable in a multi threaded scenario.

Comment: @HighCore Tks for your help, I'm going to take a look to ÍtemsControl (Actually this is a custom control that allow Data Binding).